# How to move ul div display block

Tags: javascript, html, css, media-queries

How can I move the nav-links (work & contact) that come up after you toggle the menu icon in mobile view to the left side of the screen (just under and in line the name). Currently targeting the #js-menu.main-nav.active in the media query to do so, but with no luck.

Everything is how it should be when it's in desktop view, but when I shrink to mobile and click on the icon, the nav-links are not in the right position.

```js
let mainNav = document.getElementById("js-menu");
let navBarToggle = document.getElementById("js-navbar-toggle");

navBarToggle.addEventListener("click", function() {
  mainNav.classList.toggle("active");
});
```

```css
.navbar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  height: 70px;
  align-items: center;
}

.main-nav {
  display: flex;
  margin-right: 30px;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.main-nav li {
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.nav-links {
  margin-left: 40px;
}

.logo {
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.navbar-toggle {
  display: none;
}

.nav-links,
.logo {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.navbar {
  font-size: 18px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  background: pink;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .navbar-toggle {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    right: 30px;
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 18px;
  }
  #js-menu.main-nav.active {
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 15px 15px 15px 0px;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
  }
  .logo {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-left: 20px;
  }
  .main-nav li {
    text-align: left;
    margin: 15px 15px 15px 0px;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
  }
  .main-nav {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: none;
    padding: 0px 20px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<body>
  <nav class="navbar">
    <span class="navbar-toggle" id="js-navbar-toggle">
            <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
        </span>
    <a href="#" class="logo">NAME</a>
    <ul class="main-nav" id="js-menu">
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="nav-links">WORK</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="nav-links">CONTACT</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav> 
</body>
```

Comment: i entered the code as-is into a runnable snippet - you were missing the end tag for the nav section. I added it in . (not the answer but just an addendum)

Comment: @RachelGallen thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you right, you want to do something like this.
This should give you the right direction.
Basically you had hardcoded `height: 70px;` of `.navbar`.
That's why it didn't expand on the toggle.

```js
let navBar = document.querySelector(".navbar");
let mainNav = document.getElementById("js-menu");
let navBarToggle = document.getElementById("js-navbar-toggle");

navBarToggle.addEventListener("click", function() {
  mainNav.classList.toggle("active");
  navBar.classList.toggle("active");
});
```

```css
.navbar {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    height: 70px;
    align-items: center;
  }

.main-nav {
    display: flex;
    margin-right: 30px;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: flex-end;
  }

  .main-nav li {
    margin: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
  }

  .nav-links {
    margin-left: 40px;
  }

  .logo {
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: 20px;
  }

  .navbar-toggle {
    display: none;
  }

.nav-links,
.logo {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.navbar {
  font-size: 18px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  background: pink;
}
.navbar.active{
  height: unset;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  padding-top: 24px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px){

 .navbar-toggle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  right: 30px;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 18px;
}

#js-menu.main-nav.active {
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: 4px;
  padding: 0px;
}

#js-menu.main-nav.active .nav-links {
  margin-left: 20px;
} 

.logo {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.main-nav li {
  text-align: left;
  margin: 15px 15px 15px 0px;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
}


.main-nav {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: none;
  padding: 0px 20px;
}  

}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<body>
  <nav class="navbar">
    <span class="navbar-toggle" id="js-navbar-toggle">
            <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
        </span>
    <a href="#" class="logo">NAME</a>
    <ul class="main-nav" id="js-menu">
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="nav-links">WORK</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="nav-links">CONTACT</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
    </body>
```

Comment: awesome that worked perfectly, thank you! I just noticed another issue when adjusting that, where when you click the mobile menu icon to drop down, the pink background doesn't expand along with the links on the bottom. Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: I wasn't aware of this requirement. That's why you might want to include some screenshots and/or mentions about such requirements details. ;)
I will edit my answer once I finish with the solution.

Comment: Ah sorry about that! I worked around it and moved the background off that div and just applied a background colour to the page. Probably not best practice but if you do manage to figure that out I'd be interested to see where I went wrong.